# C# - Trying to write a XML file in the appfolder and get access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, permission-denied

:)

I'm trying to write an XML file in the application folder, however I keep getting the access error denied.

1. I already have the manifest file with:

   requestedExecutionLevel level = "requireAdministrator" uiAccess = "false"
2. I get the folder path with:

   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

Ps.: Sorry for the the bad english.

-- EDIT
This is the part where I try write the file.

```
try
{
   string caminhoXML = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
   dsGenAlys.WriteXml(caminhoXML);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   lbl_status.Text = "Status: Não foi possível salvar. Error: " + ex.Message;
   return;
}
```

I always get the labelmsg text with the Acess Denied to the folder path.

-- EDIT 2

I get this error on any path I put.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [ask] for information on how to ask good questions.  In this case, it is best to provide a [mcve] that someone can use to replicate your situation.

Comment: Could you also put the code which is attempting to write to this folder?

Comment: @aguertin I edited the post with the code! :)

Comment: Try to run Visual Studio 'As Administrator'. It may solve your problem

Comment: @ShaiAharoni same problem =/

Comment: @romulo37 I think that the problem is not the folder but rather the dataset (dsGenAlys) which is still open/used and that's why you can't write it to XML

Comment: The problem is actually because in your path there isn't a file name...

Comment: @aguertin you're right! :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not specifically stating a filename in the xmlWrite path.  Append a name for the file and it should work.

Comment: Your answer is super helpful. Thank you so much @aguertin

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

With the comment of @aguertin, "The problem is actually because in your path there isn't a file name", I just use the string with a name for the file. 
Done!

Thank you all!

Comment: I put my comment as the answer,  if you don't mind upvoting and marking as answer that would be great thanks!

Comment: Of course! :) I don't have reputation enough to vote, yet